# Remove values from dataset

Tags: r

I have used below code to remove specific values from my dataset. However the end 
result is that the values are still in the dataset. What did go wrong?

```
newrisk<-risk %>%
  filter(AgeFirstBirth != "unknown"|BMI != "unknown"|Race!= "unknown"
         |NumberRelativesCancer!= "unknown")
```

Comment: Can you shhow a small reproducible example with `dput`.  I would check if there are leading/lagging spaces

Comment: Are your sure about using "or", i.e. "|"? Using "or" you remove obs for which all four vars are "unknown", while still keeping obs for which at least one var is not "unknown". Perhaps you meant "and", i.e. "&"?

Comment: @stefan yes that indeed did the trick thanks! Its always those little things you oversee If you add your answer to below, I can mark it as a solution if you want

Comment: @akrun thanks I made a sample for you but it is already resolved :) Thanks